# How do I pair arrays with the first one being a normal array and second one an array of arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pairing

Given the following arrays:

```
var arr1 = ['A','B','C'];
var arr2 = [['D','E','F']['G','H','I']]
```

The output should be:

```
['ADG','ADH','ADI','AEG','AEH','AEI','AFG','AFH','AFI','BDG','BDH','BDI'.....]
```

But it should also be dynamic so that if another array is added to arr2 it should pick that as well.

This is what I currently have:

```
const arrays = (arr1 = [], arr2 = [],arr3 = []) => {

  // var arr3 = arr2.slice(3);
  const res = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){
      for(let s=0;s<arr3.length;s++){
        res.push(arr1[i] + arr2[j] + arr3[s] );
      }
    }
  }

  return res;
};
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: mmm...... interesting.  Effectively you need a generic cross join solution.  You will need a global variable to hold the output, and a function to call which iterates through the second array.  Loop through the first array, and call the function for each element found in array 2. Push results into the global result variable as you go.  If the array 2 element is itself an array, call the function again for each element in the array 2 value.  It will be tough, but I know you can do it.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen  
am currently passing in 3 arrays 
like so 
const arrays  = (arr1 = [], arr2 = [],arr3 = []) => {
   
  // var arr3 = arr2.slice(3);
  const res = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
     for(let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){

        for(let s=0;s<arr3.length;s++){              
           res.push(arr1[i] + arr2[j] + arr3[s] );
        } 
                    
          }        
     }

  return res;
};

Comment: Please add what is **currently being done** on the question - it demonstrates to community members what has been attempted by you already & hopefully will get you  guidance tailored to your current approach.

Comment: @jsN00b
the image has been added

Comment: @Charles For your future reference: this community does not respond well to images of code, for the reasons outlined [here](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Just a friendly warning to prevent you from accumulating down-votes.

Comment: Thanks @RobbyCornelissen am a newbie here 
would you be open to help me out on a few things ?

Comment: If you have questions, make sure that you do your research, clearly define the problem, and show the effort that you have put in. As long as the question meets the site's guidelines, someone will probably answer it sooner or later. If you need more guidance to get started, you're probably better off finding a teacher or a tutor.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have those two different array variables is immaterial. Could just throw everything together<sup>1</sup> and use [`reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight):

```js
const arrays = [['A','B','C'], ['D','E','F'], ['G','H','I']];

const combine = (arrays) =>
    arrays.reduceRight((a, v) => v.flatMap(c => a.map(r => c + r)));

console.log(combine(arrays));
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> For your case that would be as simple as `const arrays = [arr1, ...arr2];`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var arr1 = ['A','B','C'];
  var arr2 = [['D','E','F'],['G','H','I'],['J','K','L'],['M','N','O']];
  const arr3 = [];
  
arr1.forEach((item,index)=>{

if(arr2.length >= index)
{
  

  arr2.forEach((el,i)=>{

    el.forEach((char,charIndex)=>{
                  let combination = item
        combination += char
      
     for(let j=1;j<arr2.length;j++){
               if(arr2[j]){
                 combination += arr2[j][charIndex]
                  }
        }
  arr3.push(combination)
    })
            
  })

}
  })
  
  console.log(arr3)
```

here is what I did

Comment: Did you read this part of the question: *"[...] but it should also be dynamic so that if another array is added to arr2 it should pick that as well [...]"*? Your solution does not do that.

Comment: no, it works try it in your console.log and you will see the result

Comment: If you add another array, you'd expect to see 4 letter combinations. Your code keeps producing 3 letter combinations.

Comment: got it, you are right,let me edit it

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen now check it out

Comment: Looks incorrect. You need 3^5 = 243 combinations. You only have 36.